# Has anyone done the course STATS242: Algorithmic Trading and Quantitative Strategies. Where Can I find the assignments and other resources?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, education

Basically the title. There's a course [STATS 242: Algorithmic Trading and Quantitative Strategies](https://explorecourses.stanford.edu/search;jsessionid=oo1kxv6ffb29u2nzlbqz1nb7?q=stats%20242&view=catalog&page=0&filter-coursestatus-Active=on&collapse=&academicYear=20142015) offered in Stanford a few years ago. I searched on google a bit for the course website to see the assignments and lecture slides but found nothing. Was wondering if anyone here has an idea about it, also any reviews of the course if anyone has done it? Thanks!

Comment: This appears the be the instructor's book: *[Algorithmic Trading and Quantitative Strategies](https://www.bookdepository.com/Algorithmic-Trading-Quantitative-Strategies-Raja-Velu/9781498737166)* by Raja Velu

Comment: Note: "Publication date 14 Jul 2020".